# Cypress .trigger commands with mousedown, mousemove & mouseup do not work

Tags: typescript, cypress

Is there some secret method to get this working?

We are using the draggable library to do this in the UI.

https://github.com/Shopify/draggable/tree/master/src/Draggable

I am trying to drag one column to the next using the Cypress automation runner.

This is my code:

```
cy.get(dataExplorerTableAttributeDraggable)
      .eq(0)
      .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 });
    cy.get(dataExplorerTableAttributeDraggable)
      .eq(1)
      .trigger('mousemove')
      .trigger('mouseup');
```

Executing this code has no visible result whatsoever.

Also tried this:

```
cy.get(dataExplorerTableAttributeDraggable)
      .eq(2)
      .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 })
      .trigger('dragstart', {})
      .trigger('drag', {});
    cy.get(dataExplorerTableAttributeDraggable)
      .eq(0)
      .trigger('dragover')
      .trigger('drop')
      .trigger('dragend')
      .trigger('mouseup');
```

I must make it clear that I need the automation to actually DO the drag & drop, not just trigger events.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

I have even faced the similar issue; only tweak which helped me was setting - `{clientX: 505, clientY: 357}`

```js
cy.get(etlWidget)
    .trigger('mouseover')
    .trigger('mousedown', {which: 1})
    .trigger('mousemove', {clientX: 505, clientY: 357})
    .xpath(PageElements.workflow.x_initial_drop_target_area)
    .trigger('mousemove')
    .trigger('mouseup', {force: true})
```

FYI., you have to listen to the browser events and set these details. More details here - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events

Also, I think this will run only on fixed viewport. Please see if this helps.

Comment: Kondasamy Jayaraman - I did not make it clear - I need my automation test to actually DO the drag & drop, not just trigger events.

Comment: I'm not sure, if you have tried the script I have recommend. This actually does drag and drop.

Comment: I am trying to use it with a slight modification:cy.get('@dragThis')
      .trigger('mouseover')
      .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 })
      .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: 505, clientY: 357 })
      .get('@dropzone')
      .trigger('mousemove')
      .trigger('mouseup', { force: true });

Comment: calling mousemove twice solved the problem for me as well

Answer (score 2):

### Problem description

I have came across with same issue but I wasn't using any library.

Problem was that somewhere in code I had type check for event, like this:

```
if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
    /* this never gets executed in Cypress but works fine when manually testing in browser */
}
```

After some debugging, I found out that mousedown `event` (fired from Cypress) is instance of `Event` but from different environment (`event instanceof Event` always returned `false`). I never dug deep into this, so I could be wrong about that.

Anyway, **solution for me was to fire native JavaScript event in Cypress** using `MouseEvent` from `cy.window()`.

---

### Potential solution for your case

Now after looking around a bit that library that you are using, I see it uses events such as [DragMouseEvent](https://github.com/Shopify/draggable/tree/master/src/Draggable/DragEvent#dragmoveevent) which **might** be same problem like I had.
If that is the case, I guess that following code would get it working (I haven't tested):

```
cy.window().then(win => {
    cy.get(dataExplorerTableAttributeDraggable)
      .eq(0)
      .then($element => $element[0].dispatchEvent(new win.MouseEvent('mousedown', {button: 1, clientX: 100, clientY: 100})));
    cy.get(dataExplorerTableAttributeDraggable)
      .eq(1)
      .then($element => $element[0].dispatchEvent(new win.MouseEvent('mousemove', {clientX: 100, clientY: 100})))
      .then($element => $element[0].dispatchEvent(new win.MouseEvent('mouseup', {clientX: 100, clientY: 100})));
})
```

Please note that `$element` is jQuery wrapped element. Also `clientX` and `clientY` should have proper position values of element in page that you want to drag (`100` is just placeholder).

---

Alternative solution for my problem above is to perform duck-type check in code like this:

```
if (event.pageX && event.pageY) {
    /* this now gets executed in Cypress and when manually testing in browser */
}
```

This would work only if you are writing your own code (not using library).

Answer (score 0):

Going off of [DRAX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60317951/6312858), their solution worked great for my use case, and gave good insight as too why a regular `.trigger()` wasn't invoking the event. Although, it's a bit messy to call `cy.window()` then get the element to dispatch the event with a new constructor.

Cypress's `.trigger()` has a [parameter](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger#Arguments) that let's you specify a different event constructor in the trigger command (at least as of version 8.0.0).

Something as simple as

```
   cy.get('body').trigger('mousedown', { eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent' });
```

For OP's use case:

```
cy.get(dataExplorerTableAttributeDraggable)
  .eq(0)
  .trigger('mousedown', {
    eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent', // Change the constructor here
    button: 1, 
    clientX: 100, 
    clientY: 100 
  });

cy.get(dataExplorerTableAttributeDraggable)
  .eq(1)
  .trigger('mousemove', {
    eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent', // Change the constructor here
    clientX: 100, 
    clientY: 100 
  })
  .trigger('mouseup', {
    eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent', // Change the constructor here
    clientX: 100,
    clientY: 100
  });
```